# Selecting Many to Many fields based on selected foreign key drop down in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the below models. In Django Admin, for course, how to show subcategories based on the selected category. I have tried django_smart_selects but the ChainedManyToManyField works for a many to many field but not a foreign key field. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
class category(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True) 

class SubCategory= (modles.Model):
    name= models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    category= models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

class Course(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    category= models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    subcategory= models.ManytoManyField(SubCategory)
```

Answer (score 0):

To populate subcategory based on category, ChainedManyToManyField itself can be used.

In the Model "Course" , if you want to select **multiple subcategory** based on the selected category, ChainedManyToManyField  can be used

```
            class Course(models.Model):
                    name= models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
                    category= models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
                    subcategory= ChainedManyToManyField(
                        SubCategory,
                        horizontal=True,
                        chained_field="category",
                        chained_model_field="category",
                        auto_choose=False   )
```

In the Model "Course" , if you want to select **one subcategory** based on the selected category, ChainedForeignKey can be used

```
            class Course(models.Model):
                name= models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
                category= models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
                subcategory= ChainedForeignKey(
                    SubCategory,
                    chained_field="category",
                    chained_model_field="category",
                    auto_choose=False   )
```